# How to enable web services on moodle?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I have configured moodle on local host and I am trying to generate the token for authentication.

I have already followed these steps :

==  Configuring Moodle for using the application ==

- Administration -> Plugins -> Web Services -> External Services -> Enable mobile web service
- Administration -> Plugins -> Web Services -> Protocols -> Enable REST
- Administration -> Users -> Permission -> Define roles -> Edit the Authenticated user role -> Allow webservice/rest:use
- Administration -> Security  -> Site policies -> Change the server upload limit. It can't be Server limit. There is a [bug in Moodle Web Services](http://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-30496)

URL :- http://localhost/moodle/login/token.php?username=admin&password=Turbo@000&service=local_mobile

```
Response :- 
{
    "error": "Web service is not available (it doesn't exist or might be disabled)",
    "stacktrace": null,
    "debuginfo": null,
    "reproductionlink": null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

check the short name of the service, you can find it here:  Site administration -> Plugins -> Web services -> External services
Click `edit` for the target service and make sure that it's enabled and the name you use is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your service short name is incorrect . You should define new external service or you can use one of existing services like moodle_mobile_app . Try this:

http://localhost/moodle/login/token.php?username=admin&password=Turbo@000&service=moodle_mobile_app

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that my service had no short name! I actually hate this moodle API. There is no clear document to show you straight forward how to do this stuff.